# Как выровнять вертикально по центру иконку fontawesome?

Tags: html, css

vertical-align: center не помогает. Нужно чтобы иконка была в центре адаптивного блока. Как быть?
display: flex это перебор, как по мне. Есть варианты?

Comment: line-height пробовали?

Comment: Конкретно к иконке?

Comment: да, к самой иконке. например, если блок высотой 60px то line-height: 60px выровняет текст посередине высоты. Хотя, визуально будет чуть ниже и на пару px, обычно, нужно уменьшить.

Comment: vertical-align: center нет такого свойства. Есть vertical-align: middle

Comment: да, ошибся. но всё равно не помогает. Блок адаптивный, заранее я не знаю его высоту.

Comment: дайте код наконец, чтобы не гадать.

Answer (score 1):

пример

```css
div{
    padding-left: 30px;
    position: relative;    
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
div:before{
    content: 'i';
    position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 0;
    margin-top: -10px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #f00;
    color: #fff;    
}
```

```html
<div>
<p>vertical-align: center не помогает. Нужно чтобы иконка была в центре адаптивного блока. Как быть? display: flex это перебор, как по мне. Есть варианты?</p>
</div>
```

Вариант с display:flex

```css
div{
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;    
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
div .fa{
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
<i class="fa fa-smile-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<p>vertical-align: center не помогает. Нужно чтобы иконка была в центре адаптивного блока. Как быть? display: flex это перебор, как по мне. Есть варианты?</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Vertical-align работает только если есть элемент занимающий 100% высоты родителя.

```css
img,
span {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
div {
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>работает</span>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50/50">
</div>

<div>
  <span>не работает</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Разобрался. Дал одному из блоков высоту 100% и сделал оба блока с выравниванием.

Answer (score 0):

`HTML`:

```
<div class='login-icon'>    
  <i class='icon-user'></i>
</div>
```

`CSS`:

```
.login-icon{
    display:inline-block;
    font-size: 40px;
    line-height: 50px;
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Пример: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e2UPC/6/)

ps. Прикладывайте код на будущее.

Comment: ТС не знает высоты блока. Не сработает.